# Connecting Mac Pro to external monitor via docking station

Tags: mac, macbook-pro

I have a toshiba docking station. I have an external monitor connected to my docking station. I cannot get this to connect to my mac pro. How do I extend the desktop to the monitor via my docking station??

Comment: Is this a USB "docking station"?  I can't imagine how else you'd even think you can go about attaching it so it must be, but please confirm.  Can you be specific as to what it is - model and part number?  Are you running Windows on this Mac?  If not, are you sure this device even supports OS X?  (I know off the top of my head a lot of these use DisplayLink chips, and their USB 2.0 solutions work fine in OS X but their USB 3.0 DL-3xxx series chips don't have a driver yet.)

Comment: Maybe don't use the docking station.  You can get displayport to VGA or DVI adaptors that'll enable you to plug your macbook into the monitor directly.  Docking stations are sure going out of fashion now.

Answer (score 0):

Laptop docking stations are often specific to a particular brand or model. If it uses USB to connect, as Shinrai asks in the comments, it's possible you could get it to work by downloading the proper [DisplayLink driver](http://www.displaylink.com/support/mac_downloads.php) for OS X, but that will only work if the adapter chip used is compatible in the first place.

You may want to just directly connect the monitor to your Mac — it will likely result in better performance and reduced CPU utilization vs. connecting it through a USB adapter. Depending on your monitor's connections, you may need a mini-Displayport to DVI or HDMI port (or full-size Displayport), which you can find in various places (I recommend [Monoprice.com](http://www.monoprice.com/) for cheap but reliable ones).